# What are the advantages of using an array of ints vs allocating memory on the heap with malloc?

Tags: c

I don't know if the question makes any sense but I'm new to C and concepts like the Heap so its a bit overwhelming for me right now. I've been reading a few articles about memory allocation using `malloc()` vs declaring variables  That I need to know the amount of data I need in advance when I want to work with variables while with `malloc()` I don't.

I can allocate data at runtime as much as I need with malloc but how? Lets say I want to input temperature records of 100 consecutive days so I did something
like

```
int* temps=malloc(100*sizeof(int)).
```

Now while I was inputting data I realise that I needed to enter 110 days of records. How do I go about adding the additional data at runtime? Since I just allocated space for 100 ints. What difference would it have made if had I done int `temps[100]`, I know I had to initialize the array again changing the int `temps[100]` to int `temps[110]` and then recompile the program again and starting the input all over again.

Comment: C does not have a concept like the heap (or the stack, for that matter). There is just automatic storage and dynamic storage. ;-)

Comment: Check [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc). Otherwise, voting to close as "unclear what you are asking".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now while I was inputting data I realise that I needed to enter 110
>   days of records. How do I go about adding the additional data at
>   runtime?

Use [realloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

> What difference would it have made if had I done int temps[100]

You can't change this size anymore, it is fixed. You have allocated array of 100 integers, and you are done. While with above approach, you still can "resize" the array during run time.

Though note sometimes doing something like `int x[100]` can be fine depending on your situation, plus it saves you from memory management related issues. That said, use dynamic memory such as `malloc`, only when it is necessary (exactly because to avoid complications related to memory management).